# What does "linger down" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions, idioms

This is a strophe from a song:

> "Well, she stands all around me her hands slowly sifting the sunshine
>   *all the laughter that **linger down** deep 'neath her smilin' is free*
>   Well, it spins and it twirls like a hummingbird lost in the morning
>   and caresses the south wind and silently sails to the sea"

But I'm not sure how the down affects the idea of linger. Is it necessary for the deep?

Could I rewrite the sentence this way:

*All the laughter that linger (down) under her smiling is free*

Comment: I think there should be an ’S’ on *linger*:  *all the laughter that linger**s** down deep...*.   *down* goes with *deep*  not with *lingers*

Answer (score 2):

In standard English: All the laughter that lingers down deep beneath her smile is free.

Country singers sometimes leave off the 's' on plurals as a purely stylistic thing. Those who actually speak with that deep of an accent have a different enough grammar that it's a slightly different dialect. "Smilin'" instead of smile is a similar effect. I don't know this dialect enough to explain the internal logic it follows.

Edit: sorry, I almost forgot: "down deep" is a unit that's much more widespread. "Down" just intensifies "deep", which is intensifying "beneath".